# Dual monitor setup for laptop (Radeon HD 6620G with VGA and HDMI at the same time) does not work

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have a Toshiba Satellite P775D (6GB RAM, Processor: AMD A8-3500 APU, Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6620G). I tried connecting this laptop to a 1366 x 768 monitor through VGA and a 1920 x 1080 TV screen via HDMI. It does not seem to want to let me run the two monitors at once (though separately, they work just fine)!

I'm getting a vague impression that some computers can and some computers cannot do this (because the graphics card cannot handle it or something). Very annoying! How do I tell if this is the case for my computer? My computer is not top of the line or anything, but SURELY in 2012, a $700 computer can run three screens... If not, what options would you recommend? A USB adapter?

Thanks in advance! (And yes, I have tried Google)

Rob

Comment: which os do you need the solution for?

Comment: google spit out (among others) this: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/331089-15-dual-monitors-hdmi-working ... reads like your problem. the problem seems to be that the gpu can't run analog signal (vga) and digital (hdmi) at the same time.

Comment: I use Windows 7.

Comment: maybe worthwhile reading as well (ramdac) http://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/93090-hdmi-trouble-when-vga-connected.html .. but i have still no definitive answer for your question, maybe someone else will.